# How to use Nuget to make project dependencies (libraries) available to others

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, project, nuget

All:

I need advise on how to use Nuget to make my project dependencies (libraries) available to other developers who will in turn have my project as dependency. See scenario below for details:

I have created a Visual Studio 2013 project (ProjA) in a solution (SolA) which has a dependency on a Library (LibA [which I do not commit into source control]). I have used Nuget to manage/fetch the dependencies of project ProjA (i.e. library LibA) via Nuget.Config in .nuget folder at solution SolA level and everything is working ok. Developers are able to checkout solution SolA and build/deploy with Nuget fetching LibA from a local server.

My issue is that I now need to have developers build their project (ProjB) in another solution (SolB) but which will import/use ProjA as a dependent project. Issue is that I cannot find a way to make Nuget fetch the dependencies of ProjA (i.e. LibA) when built as part of solution SolB. I tried putting the Nuget.Config File in the level of ProjA, but VS build seems to ignore it.

Any ideas????

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing two different but not-very-compatible approaches to code sharing here:

- Code-level dependencies
- Package-level dependencies

Code-level dependencies between different solutions are generally A Bad Thing, and you should avoid them. A solution should encapsulate and build all the source code it needs to, relying on 'library' DLLs (whether provided as raw DLLs or via NuGet).

I recommend that you re-work your solutions using the 'Package-level dependency' pattern,  so that you have a separate 'library' solution which provides a NuGet package (or set of NuGet packages) which the other two solutions can consume:

Here is the current (awkward) dependency graph:

```
Solution A            Solution B
  Proj A ----------->  Proj B
    ^--------------------'
```

Here is what I propose with the separate library solution:

```
    +----> Solution L <----+
    |                      |
Solution A             Solution B
```

Solution A and Solution B thus consume the NuGet packages produced by Solution L (the library project). This is the dependency relationship which probably underlies your code anyhow, based on what you describe.